# Is there any gem for Linux FIFOs in JRuby?

Tags: jruby

Seeing as how C extensions are out in recent releases of JRuby, is there a gem that supports FIFOs in JRuby?  The 'mkfifo' gem depends on C extensions.

Answer (score 0):

there's likely no such thing but maybe you can use FFI to get to the native stuff. also on JRuby you should be still able to read named pipes just fine.